# Uncaught SyntaxError in jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I am having a trouble using jQuery in my HTML. This might be a very simple issue, but I cant figure it out.

Following is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
</ul>

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use console in *"Web Developer Tool"* in Chrome for mac. But as soon as I add script tag in my HTML I get the following error in console.

[image]

Cant figure out whats happening. Thanks

UPDATE:

My problem is solved. The jQuery file was corrupt. I will probable use the older version.

Comment: Try adding the script tag inside head section also add the attribute **type="text/javascript"**.

Comment: Make sure that your jquery file is not corrupted. Try to reference it from global cdns. For example http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Try add `type="text/javascript"` attribute too.

Comment: Another cdn http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: @Oybek That solves the problem. The file was corrupt. Cheers.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, add an own answer and mark it as accepted to show that this problem is solved.

Comment: @AndersAbel well the OP could mark vero's answer as correct too. He also suggests that file is corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just copied your code in to a new document then downloaded jQuery from here:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

everything worked as expected, I'm assuming there is something wrong with your jQuery source file. Try downloading a fresh copy.

Answer (score 3):

I've no mac experience, probably it could be because you didn't add the type="text/javascript" in your script tag or if you are using any jquery function but your script didn't add the jquery library.

Comment: Have you checked that your jquery library has loaded and place it inside the head tag.

Comment: Its not necessary to place it in the head tag.

Answer (score 2):

i tried the same code here... http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/NRgDm/

Try using the updated file using below link:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Also check, do you have other tabs opened as well with in the same window ??